# Build boost with qt app running on ios

Tags: c++, ios, qt, boost

I am working on a qt app which runs on am ios device. I am building the app on a Mac OSX laptop. It uses C++ for most part of it. I need to build the app with boost C++ library to use boost asio. So following are the steps I did:

```
    1. Install boost on my mac laptop using port install boost. This puts boost headers into /opt/local/include & boost libs into /opt/local/lib as I see.

    2.Next, I used the following lines in my qt app`s .pro file to build


INCLUDEPATH +=  /opt/local/include
LIBS += -L/opt/local/lib
LIBS += -lboost_system-mt -lboost_thread-mt
```

Then, I build it. It says "symbols not found for architecture arm64" & "linker command failed with exit code 1"

Can anyone please point out what is the correct way to build boost for a qt app running on ios ?

Comment: May be above is not the right approach to build boost with a qt app on ios. I wish to know the correct way to build & run my qt ios app with boost       .. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

To use boost on iOS, you need a "cross-compiled" version, for the iPhone's processor architecture. The version you installed locally on your Mac was compiled for architecture `x86_64`. For an iOS app you need `armv7` and `arm64`.
Fortunately, there seems to be a precompiled boost library for iOS available under https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost, which looks like it's exactly what you need. Maybe you can have a look at that.

Comment: Glad I could help! If the answer is helpful, please upvote and mark it as accepted ;) Thanks!

Comment: @rubinstove, you cannot upvote yet but you could mark this answer as working one by pressing the mark. This would give you 15 points of reputation and ability to upvote.